# Message Box in popup form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a doubt,
I make a Button for Submit form and when I press the first button appear to me a message of confirmation to continue or not, but when I press "no" and the message disappear and return to form,but the first button doesn't work more.

You known that I make wrong.
thanks for all.

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Request Form');
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel().setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center").setWidth("900px");  
  var buttons = app.createButton('Print and Save').setId('buttons');
  var handlers = app.createServerClickHandler('question').addCallbackElement(flow);
  buttons.addClickHandler(handlers);    
   flow.add(buttons);       
  app.add(flow);  
return app; 

}

function question(e){
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();    
var dialog = app.createPopupPanel().setModal(true).setSize(700, 100).setPopupPosition(10, 400);
var closeHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(dialog).setVisible(false);
var handlersend = app.createServerClickHandler('Send');  
var handleract =app.createServerClickHandler('activateAgain');

var labelp  = app.createLabel('Are you sure that this information is correct?')
var buttonp1= app.createButton('yes, continue').addClickHandler(closeHandler).addClickHandler(handlersend);
var buttonp2= app.createButton('No, I want correct').addClickHandler(closeHandler).addClickHandler(handleract);
app.getElementById('buttons').setEnabled(false);

var gridp = app.createGrid(1,5);
        gridp.setWidget(0, 0, labelp)
      .setWidget(0,1,buttonp1)
      .setWidget(0,2,buttonp2);

dialog.add(gridp)
dialog.show();     
return app; 
}

function activateAgain(e){ 
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();   
app.getElementById('buttons').setEnabled(true);
return app;
}

function Send(e){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make it happen in clientHandler which is basically a good idea but the problem is that some methods are not available in clientHandlers, for example `hide()` is not !

So you used `setVisible(false)` to hide the dialog but then you can't get it visible again easily...

All in all, I found it was easier with `serverHandler` and a few modifications.

Since you seem to be quite comfortable with UiApp I don't need to explain further, the code is self explanatory enough (I hope :-)

Code below : ([and test HERE](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwIqmJsMvW19qYYvHY-zu29ZStbbpcKEwScD02avbQavSCFl5vC/exec))

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Request Form');
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel().setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center").setWidth("900px");  
  var buttons = app.createButton('Print and Save').setId('buttons');
  var handlers = app.createServerClickHandler('question').addCallbackElement(flow);
  buttons.addClickHandler(handlers);    
   flow.add(buttons);       
  app.add(flow);  
return app; 

}

function question(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();    
  var dialog = app.createPopupPanel().setModal(true).setSize(700, 100).setPopupPosition(10, 400).setId('dialog');
  var button = app.getElementById('buttons').setEnabled(true);
  var closeHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(button).setEnabled(true);
  var correctHandler = app.createServerHandler('hideDialog');
  var handlersend = app.createServerClickHandler('Send');    
  var labelp  = app.createLabel('Are you sure that this information is correct?')
  var buttonp1= app.createButton('yes, continue').addClickHandler(handlersend);
  var buttonp2= app.createButton('No, I want correct').addClickHandler(closeHandler).addClickHandler(correctHandler);
  app.getElementById('buttons').setEnabled(false);

  var gridp = app.createGrid(1,5);
  gridp.setWidget(0, 0, labelp)
      .setWidget(0,1,buttonp1)
  .setWidget(0,2,buttonp2);

  dialog.add(gridp)
  dialog.show();     
  return app; 
}

function hideDialog(){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();    
  var dialog = app.getElementById('dialog');
  dialog.hide();
  return app;
}

function Send(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();    
  var dialog = app.getElementById('dialog');
  dialog.hide();
  app.getElementById('buttons').setEnabled(false);
  app.add(app.createLabel('send'));
  return app;
}
```